# Hibernate cache not working for subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

Hibernate succeeded to retrieve Query Result from cache,
then it failed to retrieve Entities from Cache, it executed a single Query for every row.

I debugged `org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener`, and in my case `persister.hasNaturalIdentifier()` returned `false`, so looks like entities are never cached.

I was expecting that the ID should be used as a default KEY.

```
protected Object doLoad(
            final LoadEvent event,
            final EntityPersister persister,
            final EntityKey keyToLoad,
            final LoadEventListener.LoadType options) {
        Object entity = loadFromSessionCache( event, keyToLoad, options );

        entity = loadFromSecondLevelCache( event, persister, options );
        if ( entity != null ) {
        }
        else {
            entity = loadFromDatasource( event, persister, keyToLoad, options );
        }    
        if ( entity != null && persister.hasNaturalIdentifier() ) { 
        event.getSession().getPersistenceContext().getNaturalIdHelper().cacheNaturalIdCrossReferenceFromLoad(
                    persister,
                    event.getEntityId(),
                    event.getSession().getPersistenceContext().getNaturalIdHelper().extractNaturalIdValues(
                            entity,
                            persister
                    )
            );
        }        
        return entity;
    }
```

SO after

**1_** the loadFromSecondLevelCache Faileds

**2_** it load from Datasource,

**3_** then it should put the Entity in the Cache wich is not possible because `persister.hasNaturalIdentifier()` returned `false`

If i am wrong **where is the hibernate sequence for the insert of the Entity to the cache after the load?**

After some search my problem is exactly this [secondlevelcache](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1002705&view=next)

And it also a duplicate of this [coherence-hibernate-integration/1.0.0/secondlevelcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294394/dedicated-cache-region-for-entity-subclasses)

**So the real problem is**

During the creation of the cacheKey hibernate use `persister.getRootEntityName()`

```
final CacheKey cacheKey = session.generateCacheKey( id, persister.getIdentifierType(), persister.getRootEntityName() );
    if ( session.getPersistenceContext().wasInsertedDuringTransaction( persister, id ) ) {
        persister.getCacheAccessStrategy().update(
                        cacheKey,
                        persister.getCacheEntryStructure().structure( entry ),
                        version,
                        version
                );
    }
```

But during the retrive it use `persister.getEntityName() !!!!`

```
protected Object loadFromSecondLevelCache(
            final LoadEvent event,
            final EntityPersister persister,
            final LoadEventListener.LoadType options) {

        final SessionImplementor source = event.getSession();
        final boolean useCache = persister.hasCache()
                && source.getCacheMode().isGetEnabled()
                && event.getLockMode().lessThan( LockMode.READ );

        if ( !useCache ) {
            // we can't use cache here
            return null;
        }

        final SessionFactoryImplementor factory = source.getFactory();
        final CacheKey ck = source.generateCacheKey(
                event.getEntityId(),
                persister.getIdentifierType(),
                persister.getEntityName()
        );
```

Comment: Have you enabled the second-level cache for this entity in addition to the query cache?

Comment: Yes i do, the debug confirm that it enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing 
org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad

```
final CacheKey cacheKey = session.generateCacheKey( id, 
persister.getIdentifierType(), persister.getRootEntityName() );    
--->    
final CacheKey cacheKey = session.generateCacheKey( id, 
persister.getIdentifierType(), persister.getEntityName() );
```

Fix the problem, but i am open for a beter solution

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate searches the cache by ID, not by natural-id, check this call:

```
entity = loadFromSecondLevelCache( event, persister, options );
```

In your case it may be that the cache entry got invalidated by a pending concurrent entity modification.

Comment: the first time this should fails, but after the loadFromDataSource, hibernate should put the Entity to the cache wich is not done, i verified that with SelectableConcurrentHashMap.put(Object key, Element element) wich is never called

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. Write a small UT and file a Hibernate issue.